# we can connect sqlplus / as sysdba but get error ORA-01034: ORACLE not available

Tags: oracle-19c

i have errror when connect with sqlplus / as sysdba, but i can connect sqlplus sys/oracle@db as sysdba,

could you give me advise regarding this problem,,

[oracle@rac1 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Nov 3 01:00:03 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> show pdbs;
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

SP2-1545: This feature requires Database availability.
SQL>

[oracle@rac1 ~]$ sqlplus sys/oracle@dbname as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Nov 3 01:02:23 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> show pdbs;

```
CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
```

---

```
     2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
     3 RTRADINGPDB                    READ WRITE NO
```

SQL>

Comment: Start the instance. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/tutorial-start-oracle/index.html?opt-release-19c

Comment: Does `dbname` in your `tnsnames.ora` file point to the local instance?

Comment: @SergeyA the instance appears to be running since it is accepting TNS connections. More likely that the OP didn't have the `ORACLE_SID` environment parameter set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations, assuming that your database instance is up and running normally:

1. To use `sqlplus / as sysdba` you *must* have the `ORACLE_SID` environment parameter set to point to a valid instance on the localhost. If you do not have this parameter set correctly you will see the ORA-01034, "connected to an idle instance" message. This kind of connection - IPC - can only be made directly to a container database (CDB) or a stand-alone instance (not CDB/PDB architecture) on the localhost.

   ```
   export ORACLE_SID=CDB
   ```
2. You appear to be using Oracle RAC, which further complicates the choice of ORACLE_SID values: each instance will have an SID unique to that cluster node. So for example, the "CDB" database will have instance "CDB1" on host RAC1 and instance "CDB2" on host RAC2. For an IPC connection, be sure you use the correct ORACLE_SID value for the instance *and host*.

   ```
   export ORACLE_SID=CDB1
   ```
3. If you want to connect directly to a pluggable database (PDB), you *must* use a TNS connection such as you described above: `sqlplus username/password@dbname as sysdba` using the TNS alias (e.g., dbname) for the PDB's network `service_name`. You can also connect to a CDB this way.

If your instance really *isn't* started, then use the appropriate tools for your architecture (RAC has special command-line tools like srvctl or crsctl for dealing with cluster resources) to start the database or local instance.